HTML page content overlapping with footer
I have added around 50 rows in the same table. After that content overlaps the footer.
Data 15 is showing but Data 16 and Data 17 are missing.
Footer should visible all page in the bottom.
Example: In hospital printing discharge summary have footer all the pages.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Printable Document with Footer</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 50px;
      padding: 0;
      padding-bottom: 140px;
      /* Ensure enough space between table and footer */
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
      /* Header, Content, Footer */
      min-height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      /* Space between container and footer */
    }
    
    .footer {
      background-color: #333;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 100px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      /* Space between container and footer */
    }
    
    .table-wrapper {
      overflow: hidden;
      /* Ensure table doesn't overlap footer */
    }
    
    table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 8px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    @media print {
      .footer {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        /* Adjust height as needed */
        visibility: visible !important;
        /* Ensure footer is visible on every printed page */
        margin-top: 20px;
        /* Space between container and footer */
      }
      body {
        padding-bottom: 500px;
        /* Adjust padding-bottom to create space for footer */
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- Example of a long table -->
          <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 29</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 30</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
          </tr>
          <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
          <!-- This table will automatically split across pages -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer Content - This will appear on every printed page.
  </div>
</body>

</html>



It should work on while print this web page


To ensure that the footer remains visible on every printed page and that content doesn't overlap it, you can dynamically divide your table into sections with a fixed number of rows per section. Then, you can use CSS to ensure each section starts on a new page when printing.
Here's how you can implement this solution:
            <script>
                window.onload = function() {
                    var table = document.querySelector('table');
                    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                    var rowsPerPage = 25; // Number of rows per page
                    var sectionsNeeded = Math.ceil(rowCount / rowsPerPage);

                    for (var i = 0; i < sectionsNeeded; i++) {
                        var startIndex = i * rowsPerPage;
                        var endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + rowsPerPage, rowCount);

                        for (var j = startIndex; j < endIndex; j++) {
                            table.rows[j].classList.add('section-' + i);
                        }
                    }

                    for (var k = 1; k < sectionsNeeded; k++) {
                        var sectionRows = document.querySelectorAll('.section-' + k);
                        sectionRows[0].style.pageBreakBefore = 'always';
                    }
                }
            </script>

Here's how this script works:
It calculates the number of sections needed based on the total number of rows in the table and the desired number of rows per page.
It assigns a unique class to each row based on its section.
It sets a CSS style to ensure each section starts on a new page when printing.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Printable Document with Footer</title>
<style>
body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 50px;
        padding: 0;
        padding-bottom: 140px; /* Ensure enough space between table and footer */
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto; /* Header, Content, Footer */
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px; /* Space between container and footer */
    }
    .footer {
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
        margin-top: 20px; /* Space between container and footer */
    }
    .table-wrapper {
        overflow: hidden; /* Ensure table doesn't overlap footer */
    }
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    @media print {
        .footer {
            display: block;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px; /* Adjust height as needed */
            visibility: visible !important; /* Ensure footer is visible on every printed page */
            margin-top: 20px; /* Space between container and footer */
        }
        body {
            padding-bottom: 500px; /* Adjust padding-bottom to create space for footer */
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <th>Header 2</th>
                <th>Header 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Example of a long table -->
            <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 3</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 4</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 5</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 6</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Data 7</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 8</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 9</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 10</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 11</td>
                <td>Data 12</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 12</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 13</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 14</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 15</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 16</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 17</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 18</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 19</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 20</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Data 21</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Data 22</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Data 23</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 24</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 25</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 26</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 27</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 28</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 29</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 30</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
                <td>Data 3</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
            <!-- This table will automatically split across pages -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
<div class="footer">
    Footer Content - This will appear on every printed page.
</div>
</html>



can you please explain what's the exact reason why this solution should work?

Not working. please check in the print page. Still content going inside footer

Answers should contain some explanation of the solution, not just "try it". Please see [answer] and take the [tour].

Your HTML is invalid. You have content outside the body element.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
